# VBA - not case sensitive comparison

Tags: performance, vba

I tested comparison speed:

```
Dim counter As Long
```

Case sensitive binary comparison (default): 0,016 sec:

```
For counter = 1 To 100000
    If InStr("This is macro speed test", "macro") > 0 Then
    End If
Next counter
```

Case insensitive comparison with case conversion: 0,068 sec:

```
For counter = 1 To 100000
    If InStr(UCase("This is macro speed test"), "MACRO") > 0 Then
    End If
Next counter
```

Case insensitive vbtextCompare: 0,08 sec:

```
For counter = 1 To 100000
    If InStr(1, "This is macro speed test", "MACRO", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    End If
Next counter
```

I wonder why text compare did so poorly in this test, I have seen people recommending it on forums over "slow" UCase or LCase conversion.

Are there any faster methods for case insensitive comparison?

Comment: This isn't a Code Review question. A CR question would show us the benchmarking code and ask if there's a better way to test for performance of various text comparisons. What are you using to measure execution times? Timing execution in VBA has notoriously poor resolution, making .068 vs .08 utterly meaningless. Besides... how is .012 seconds "poor" performance over 100000 iterations?

Comment: FWIW, `"This is macro speed test" Like "*[Mm][Aa][Cc][Rr][Oo]*"` destroys all comers.

Comment: To measure execution I use the same method as John Coleman is his answer. I said that vbTextCompare did relatively poorly, as a method advertised to be performance boost. I followed the advice and checked performance for 1 000 000 iterations: 1) 0,08; 2) 0,45; 3) 0,6 4) Comintern's answer 0,3. Like is indeed a great solution when there are little characters to match. It becomes inconvenient and slow with more characters.

Comment: Because `Like` wins this case insensitive comparison speed test and has potential to be faster with less characters, I would like to mark it as an answer.

Comment: I agree that @Comintern 's answer is quite nice and should be posted. Note that it is easy enough to generate strings such as `"*[Mm][Aa][Cc][Rr][Oo]*"` automatically (at least if they are alphanumerical and you don't have to delve into escape issues). You could first feed the target string to a conversion function and then use `Like`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember `UCase()` and `LCase()` are returning a Variant result. You can optimize their use by adding "$" : `UCase$()` and `LCase$()` which force a string result.

This works as well for `Left$()`, `Right$()`, `Mid$()` etc...

With such

```
Sub test()
Dim counter As Long
Dim start As Double, elapsed As Double

start = Timer
For counter = 1 To 100000
    If InStr("This is macro speed test", "macro") > 0 Then
    End If
Next counter
elapsed = Timer - start
Debug.Print "1: " & elapsed

start = Timer
For counter = 1 To 100000
    If InStr(UCase$("This is macro speed test"), "MACRO") > 0 Then
    End If
Next counter
elapsed = Timer - start
Debug.Print "2: " & elapsed

start = Timer
For counter = 1 To 100000
    If InStr(1, "This is macro speed test", "macro", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    End If
Next counter
elapsed = Timer - start
Debug.Print "3: " & elapsed

End Sub
```

I obtained :

```
1: 0,00390625
2: 0,015625
3: 0,0625
```

This is slightly faster for the second method.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim start As Double, elapsed As Double

    start = Timer
    For counter = 1 To 100000
        If InStr("This is macro speed test", "macro") > 0 Then
        End If
    Next counter
    elapsed = Timer - start
    Debug.Print "1: " & elapsed

    start = Timer
    For counter = 1 To 100000
        If InStr(UCase("This is macro speed test"), UCase("macro")) > 0 Then
        End If
    Next counter
    elapsed = Timer - start
    Debug.Print "2: " & elapsed

    start = Timer
    For counter = 1 To 100000
        If InStr(1, "This is macro speed test", "macro", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        End If
    Next counter
    elapsed = Timer - start
    Debug.Print "3: " & elapsed

End Sub
```

I get output like this:

```
1: 0.0078125
2: 0.0703125
3: 0.078125
```

The differences between 2) and 3) have shrunk to insignificance. It seems that your second code was using that the target "MACRO" was in upper case, where as the third approach makes no assumption about the case of the third argument (hence maybe behind the scenes coverts them both to either upper or lower case).

I ran your original code a number of times and confirm that there does seem to be a persistent albeit minor speed advantage of the second over the third, which suggests that if you are checking a large number of strings against a fixed string of known case, then converting to that case and using a case-insensitive search is slightly better than doing case-insensitive searches using `vbTextCompare`, though the difference is so small it is unlikely to make any perceptible difference.

Comment: In 2) I don't convert "MACRO", because it's a constant, so I can type it in any case I want for comparison.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk, I understand that, but `InStr` doesn't -- so it is implicitly checking the case of "MACRO" each time and converting it if needed. The point of the answer is to explain the time discrepancy (which is what you asked about) between the two methods. If you modify method 2 so that it also pays attention to the case of both string arguments then the discrepancy largely vanishes. Thus the extra time for the third method against your original second method is explained by the fact that the third method makes no assumptions about the case of "MACRO", but your second method did.